# Como atrasar a exibição de um container usando Java Script ou CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, script

Preciso fazer ajuste em um site, o cliente quer que um conteúdo seja exibido após 30 minutos.

Vou colocar um pequeno exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <video src="">Video do Cliente</video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <video src="">Conteúdo Para ser carregado após 30 minutos</video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <video src="">Conteúdo Para ser carregado após 30 minutos</video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <video src="">Conteúdo Para ser carregado após 30 minutos</video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Qual código faria os demais conteúdos serem carregado após um tempo determinado?

Answer (score -2):

```
function load(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('run')
},3000)}
```

O código JS acima printa `run` no console após 3 segundos contados a partir do momento que a função `load()` for iniciada.
Você só precisa:

1. Declarar uma variável que contenha a seleção do elemento container onde seus elementos serão adicionados.
2. Modificar a função `load()` para criar um elemento com o conteúdo desejado.
3. Acrescentar (append) o elemento criado dentro do container já selecionado pela variável na etapa 1.
4. Ajustar o tempo de setTimeout para o tempo desejado.

O JS **também** possui uma função `setInterval(callback, tempo)` que chama a função `callback` em loop a cada `tempo`. Recomendo dar uma olhada, é fácil rápido, faça de acordo com sua preferência.